# Where to find an infographic describing the components of a 5-paragraph essay?

Tags: essay

I need to show students the various components of a 5-paragraph essay. Most just show the paragraphs: "introduction", "body", and "conclusion", but I need to show the parts at a sentence level.

For example, most body paragraphs start with a supporting statement, then have one or two sentences telling general information, and tend to end with a specific example supported by a citation. Most academic writing seems to follow this same format.

- Do each of these different kind of sentences within the paragraph have names?
- Where can I find an infographic describing each part or another resource identifying and naming each part of a 5-paragraph essay?

Comment: Hi Village! I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking here. Do you know what components you want to teach your students, or are you asking what to teach? Are you having trouble writing an example for them, or can you write a written example but you're looking for an existing teaching aid demonstrating the same thing?

Comment: E.g., one component is the "thesis statement", usually a single sentence appearing at the end of the introduction. Other components are the "supporting statements", usually a single sentence appearing at the beginning of each body paragraph. I am just looking for a teaching aid, perhaps a poster or print-out, that students can reference that shows the parts, perhaps a bit abstracted, and labels each part.

Comment: OK, is [this](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/23377577/5-Paragraph-Essay-Components) something like what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

This powerpoint presentation or we can say handouts will definitely help you :

http://www.create.cett.msstate.edu/create/classroom/lplan_view.asp?articleID=171

http://www.create.cett.msstate.edu/create/classroom/handouts/Epting_CD2_Set3_Bing_Bang_Bongo_Powerpoint_Handout1_Revised.pdf

I think this link provides some examples along with the explanation on writing five paragraph essays effectively..

http://www.chicagonow.com/white-rhino/2012/05/if-you-teach-or-write-5-paragraph-essays-stop-it/

With the help of these info graphic tools, I think you can make the one on your own for your students which will help you teach them. 
http://www.teachthought.com/technology/46-tools-to-make-infographics-in-the-classroom/

This link will also help you to teach students regarding easy composition of a five paragraph essay.
http://nestersteachingblog.com/category/writing-prompts/

This graphic organizer can help you to an extent. It is easily printable : http://www.teachervision.fen.com/graphic-organizers/printable/43086.html